# Contraction of non-zero prime ideals in the ring of algebraic integers

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A= \{y \in \mathbb{C} :$ $y$ integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ }. Let $P\not=\{0 \}$ be a prime ideal of $A$. Prove that $P \cap \mathbb{Z} \not= \{0 \}$.

Iam totally stuck here, it is given that $P$ contains an element $a \not= 0$, I tried to assume that $P$ contains no integer, so $a$ must be a complex number. I have concluded that $A$ contains the whole $\mathbb{Z}$, and it contains all complex numbers of form $ki$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and if $A$ contains $a$, then it must contain its conjugate (its conjugate is the root of the same monic polynomial as $a$ is the root of)

Although I feel im close, I cant make it from here. Any hints please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Show that the constant term of the minimal polynomial of some nonzero element $z \in P$ also belongs to $P$.

Comment: I will try this, thank you very much.

Comment: What is "the minimal polynomial" of an integral element ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Sorry, that was a shortcut. What I meant was "nonzero monic polynomial with integer coefficients $f$ with $f(z)=0$ of the lowest possible degree". If I'm not mistaken, however, this is actually the same thing as the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ (by Gauss' lemma I think).

Comment: Dear @Pavel, everything in your comment is absolutely correct: +1 for your answer and +1 for your comment! By the way (for commutative algebraists): an analogous  result is still true for any integrally closed (=normal) domain and any extension field of its field of fractions.